# WCF Data services - Client is caching results

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF data service, my client is a WPF app.

I have a service operation in my WCF data services. something like that

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<VSuppliersExtra> GetAllVSuppliers()
{
    List<VSuppliersExtra> lstVsup = new List<VSuppliersExtra>();
    // add some VSuppliersExtra entities to the list
    ........
    return lstVsup.AsQueryable<VSuppliersExtra>();            
}
```

In my client I have

```
oCollection = new ObservableCollection<VSuppliersExtra>(jp.CreateQuery<VSuppliersExtra>("GetAllVSuppliers"));
//Open a new window Change collection and update the changes in the DB
.......
//run the same query again
.......
oCollection = new ObservableCollection<VSuppliersExtra>(jp.CreateQuery<VSuppliersExtra>("GetAllVSuppliers"));
```

Now, everything work just fine, BUT the 2nd call for the service operation will always get me the same results without the changes, until I restart my app.
I check the DB, all my changes are saved to the SQL server, I've checked the function in the service, and it does return the updated data... YET I get the same result set!!!!
Is there some caching in the client side????

Comment: Can you use Fiddler or Wireshark to see what the traffic looks like? Are you getting a HTTP 200 vs 304?

Comment: I don't know how to use fiddler with the WCF data service and WPF client. If I query my Service using the browser, I see good results in the browser and fiddler

Comment: In fiddler I see Cache-Control: max-age=0

Comment: With a HTTP 200 response code? And the response contains the updated data? If so, then I would look at the client side to see if the data matches the returned packet.

Comment: That's the Issue, client side does not match the return packet!!! I'm doing an Execute<> in my client side with the same URL as in the browser. In my browser I'll get good results in the client no updates are shown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,
I found some article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602811.aspx
I added a context.MergeOptions  = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;

That did the Trick.

Thank you